# How to fetch different data from the same API?

Tags: reactjs

I created a dummy data try to get a different data from the same API.

But I don't know how to improve my code and how to fetch different object then get data from the object I fetched.

scenario is I want to select a month then fetch the corresponding results to show on the table.
Here is my codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/datafetch-practice-i6uxu4

```
export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState('September')



  useEffect(() => {
      const fetchPosts = async () => {
        if(selectedMonth === 'September'){
        setLoading(true);
        
        setPosts(users[0].results);
        setLoading(false);
        }
        else if(selectedMonth === 'October'){
          setLoading(true);
          
          setPosts(users[1].results);
          setLoading(false);
          }
        else if(selectedMonth === 'November'){
            setLoading(true);
            
            setPosts(users[2].results);
            setLoading(false);
            }
        
      };
      fetchPosts();
    
  }, []);
```

And I don't want to do hard code like I don't need to said if(selectedMonth === 'September') then to get a data. How to improve these codes, please? (solved)

May I know how to fetch the certain data in the mockData.js ?
The new scenario is I want to only fetch the data of the "totalSpend" to create another  call "Reward". (For example, A customer receives 2 points for every dollar spent over $100 in each transaction, plus 1 point for every
dollar spent over $50 in each transaction
(e.g. a $120 purchase = 2x$20 + 1x$50 = 90 points).
)
Should I calculate the reward in the mockData.js file or in App.js?

Comment: you probably want something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-meadow-3be4p2?file=/src/App.js
don't use the mocked data directly in the component, provide a mock fetch function. And if your data depends on the month then pass the month to this function. Normally you'd do a proper GET request with the month in the body or in the URL but here you can just to Array.find. Remember to handle an empty response though.

Comment: so what is users[0], users[1] etc doing. Is it dependent on the value selected?

Comment: @WahabShah
Hi users[0], users[1] Those are the object I tried to fetch.

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski May I ask you one more question please?
Please see the above new update.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fetch your array data by the [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method in javascript. then you can get the results from the returned object.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const fetchPosts = async () => {
  const filteredUser = users.find((user) => user.month === selectedMonth);
  if (filteredUser) {
   setPosts(filteredUser.results);
  }
 };
 fetchPosts();
}, []);
```